# Hook is not called more than 1 time

Tags: reactjs, async-await, axios, react-hooks, use-effect

I am building a Simple ToDoList App.
I fetch List Using React Hook. 
When I add a new Todo or delete an existing one the request sends and works but the component doesn`t rerender.
I tried 2 ways to solve the problem to create 
**1.async functions(delete and add). Took getToDoList outside the hook and call it after requests(post/delete)**

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getToDoList();
}, []);


const getToDoList = async () => {
    const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:1200/');
    setToDoList(result.data);
};

const addNewTodo = async () => {
    await axios.post('http://localhost:1200/create', {
        item: newToDo.current.value
    });
    getToDoList();
};

const deleteToDo = async (id) => {
    await axios.delete(`http://localhost:1200/delete?id=${id}`);
    getToDoList();
};
```

**2.Took getToDoList inside the hook and gave it 2 dependecies which change in deleteToDo/addNewToDo**

```
const [add, setAdd] = useState(false);
const [remove, setRemove] = useState(false);

useEffect(() => {
    const getToDoList = async () => {
        const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:1200/');
        setToDoList(result.data);
    };
    getToDoList();
}, [add, remove]);

const addNewTodo = async () => {
    await axios.post('http://localhost:1200/create', {
        item: newToDo.current.value
    });
    setAdd(!add);
};

const deleteToDo = async (id) => {
    await axios.delete(`http://localhost:1200/delete?id=${id}`);
    setRemove(!remove);
};
```

Both don`t work. Tell me please where Im wrong

JSX

```
 return (
    <div>
        <Jumbotron>
            <Container>
                <h1>Hello!</h1>
                <p>This is a simple ToDoList created by Vadik</p>
            </Container>
        </Jumbotron>
        <Container>
            <Container>
                <InputGroup>
                    <FormControl placeholder="What needs to be done" ref={newToDo}/>
                </InputGroup>
                <Button onClick={addNewTodo} variant="primary" size="sm">
                    Add new Todo
                </Button>
            </Container>
            <Container className="cards">
                <Card>
                    <ListGroup>
                        {toDoList.todos.map((elem) => <ListGroup.Item
                            key={elem._id}>{elem.item}<CloseButton onClick={() => deleteToDo(elem._id)}/>  </ListGroup.Item>)}
                    </ListGroup>
                </Card>
            </Container>
        </Container>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: Please share the jsx that is bound to your state

Comment: @Chev Shared, look

Comment: Did you try to put `setToDoList(result.data);` or `getToDoList()` in a `then`-block?

Comment: What is the definition of setToDoList function?

Comment: @NikaTsogiaidze const [toDoList, setToDoList] = useState({todos: []});
    const newToDo = useRef("");

Comment: @oemera nothing changes

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(result.data)` to confirm that your data is changing after adding and removing?

Comment: @F.Serna Where? And for what actually? I see the request post and delete works because if i reload the page ToDoList changes

Comment: The problem is that if I put smth  after post and delete request doesn`t work.                  Even If I try to console.log after those requests they don`t work

Comment: I got it. It`s because on backend I didn`t send any result after those operations

Comment: Do you want to get list again after add or delete item, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code.This should work.In addTodo there are 2 ways either update the resultList after post is successful or use the getList to get the latest data and update the resultList. Both of them are shown.

```
    function Example() {

      const [resultList, setResult] = useState({todos: []});

      useEffect(() => {
        const todoList = getToDoList();
        setResult(prev => todoList);
      }, []);

      const addTodo = async () => {
        await axios.post('http://localhost:1200/create', {
          item: newToDo.current.value
        });

        //Addition successful, hence update our resultList.
        return setResult(prev => {
          return {todos: [...prev.todos, {item: newToDo.current.value, id: prev.todos.length+1}]}
        });


        //Now since add api doesn't return a 
        //value call Get api again and update the todoList to render
        //const todoList = getToDoList();
        //setResult(prev => todoList);
      };

      const getToDoList = async () => {
        const result = await axios.get('http://localhost:1200/');
        return result.data;
      };          

      return (
        <div id='container'>
          {resultList.todos.map(todo => <div>{todo.item}</div>
          )}
          <button onClick={addTodo}>Add</button>
        </div>
      )


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I didn`t send any response to those requests.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dq6jY.png)